# Responding to command prompts in SSH.NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ssh, ssh.net

I want to interrupt my output logging thread to "confirm" an action.
For example I want to install php, so I type `sudo apt-get install php`. Than I have to confirm that with a `y`, i know that I can write `sudo apt-get install php -y`. I get the same problem when I execute a script and I have to fill out necessary information.

```cs
using (var client = new SshClient(ip, Convert.ToInt16(port), username, password))
{
    client.Connect();

    var command = client.CreateCommand((txtCommand.Text));
    var result = command.BeginExecute();

    //log vps output 
    using (var reader =
       new StreamReader(command.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
    {
        while (!result.IsCompleted || !reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                     txtOutput1.Invoke(
                         (MethodInvoker)(() =>
                     txtOutput1.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine)));
            }
        }
    }

    command.EndExecute(result);
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

So how can I interrupt the thread to execute a new command to solve the `read` command?

Comment: What is *"Confirm sth"*? A search did not provide results in the programming/development/computer context.

Answer (score 0):

Use an input redirection using shell constructs to provide the input to the script.

Like:

```
echo input | ./your_script.sh
```